# how to protect resources in a specific Pulumi stack from being deleted

Tags: pulumi

I use Pulumi to bring up my infrastructures in GCP . Pulumi has the stack features that helps you to build multiple replications of the same type of Pulumi's code.

So I have dev/stage/prod stack that corresponds to each of the environment we have.

I want to know if there is a way that I can protect the production stack so that no one can delete any resources in there.

I am aware that about the protect bit flag, but that would apply to all the stacks which I don't want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are a couple options to achieve this:

#### Option 1

One option would be to restrict access to the Pulumi state file such that only a privileged user or entity (e.g. a [continuous delivery pipeline](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/continuous-delivery/)) is able to read and *write* the `prod` state and therefore able to perform operations that might destroy resources. The Pulumi Console backend supports this with [stack permissions](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/console/collaboration/stack-permissions/) at a granular level and access can be restricted with the other state backends via the IAM capabilities of the specific provider (e.g. AWS IAM).

#### Option 2

Another option (that could be used in conjunction with the first) would be to programmatically set the [`protect`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#protect) flag based on the stack name. Below is an example in Python, but the same concept works in all languages:

```py
import pulumi
from pulumi_aws import s3

# only set `protect=True` for "prod" stacks
prod_protected = False
if "prod" == pulumi.get_stack():
    prod_protected = True

bucket = s3.Bucket("my-bucket",
    opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(
        protect=prod_protected, # use `prod_protected` flag
    ),
)
```

You would be required to set `protect=...` on each resource in your stack to protect *all* resources in the `prod` stack. The Pulumi SDK provides a way to set this on all resources at once with a *stack transformation*. There's an example of doing a stack transformation to set tags on resources [here](https://github.com/joeduffy/aws-tags-example/blob/master/autotag-py/__main__.py#L5-L11).

Comment: ahh I see what you mean. Thank you for pointing out the stack transformation bit as well. That is a really clean pattern to approach this.